# asyncio task was destroyed but it is pending

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, coroutine, event-loop

I am working a sample program that reads from a datasource (csv or rdbms) in chunks, makes some transformation and sends it via socket to a server.

But because the csv is very large, for testing purpose I want to break the reading after few chunks.
Unfortunately something goes wrong and I do not know what and how to fix it. Probably I have to do some cancellation, but now sure where and how. I get the following error:

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<<async_generator_athrow without __name__>()>>
```

The sample code is:

```
import asyncio
import json

async def readChunks():
  # this is basically a dummy alternative for reading csv in chunks
  df = [{"chunk_" + str(x) : [r for r in range(10)]} for x in range(10)]
  for chunk in df:
    await asyncio.sleep(0.001)
    yield chunk

async def send(row):
    j = json.dumps(row)
    print(f"to be sent: {j}")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.001)


async def main():
    i = 0
    async for chunk in readChunks():
        for k, v in chunk.items():
            await asyncio.gather(send({k:v}))
        i += 1
        if i > 5:
            break
        #print(f"item in main via async generator is {chunk}")
    

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Comment: `Unfortunately something goes wrong...` - what went wrong? how is it misbehaving? Do you know if either of your coroutines work the way you wanted? Have you tried to trace the wrongness by inspecting intermediate results?

Comment: Why aren't you using the high level api - `asyncio.run()`?

Comment: Exactly, `asyncio.run` will cancell all the pending for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many `async` resources, such as generators, need to be cleaned up with the help of an event loop. When an `async for` loop stops iterating an async generator via `break`, the generator is cleaned up by the garbage collector only. This means the task is pending (waits for the event loop) but gets destroyed (by the garbage collector).

The most straightforward fix is to `aclose` the generator explicitly:

```
async def main():
    i = 0
    aiter = readChunks()      # name iterator in order to ...
    try:
        async for chunk in aiter:
            ...
            i += 1
            if i > 5:
                break
    finally:
        await aiter.aclose()  # ... clean it up when done
```

---

These patterns can be simplified using the [`asyncstdlib`](https://asyncstdlib.readthedocs.io/) (disclaimer: I maintain this library). [`asyncstdlib.islice`](https://asyncstdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/api/itertools.html#asyncstdlib.itertools.islice) allows to take a fixed number of items before cleanly closing the generator:

```
import asyncstdlib as a

async def main():
    async for chunk in a.islice(readChunks(), 5):
        ...
```

If the `break` condition is dynamic, [scoping the iterator](https://asyncstdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/api/asynctools.html#asyncstdlib.asynctools.scoped_iter) guarantees cleanup in any case:

```
import asyncstdlib as a

async def main():
    async with a.scoped_iter(readChunks()) as aiter:
        async for idx, chunk in a.enumerate(aiter):
            ...
            if idx >= 5:
                break
```

Comment: I didn't know about `asyncstdlib`, nice work MisterMiyagi!

Comment: Thank you! Thought something with cancel to be done and convert something into task. No clue what and how yet. Do you know any detailed, but step by step guide which gets deeper and deeper and leads me through the async world?

Comment: Also found this which seems working w/o "finally": await asyncio.gather(send({k:v}), return_exceptions = True)

Comment: Can i just put that in my code or in each task that has `async for` loops?

Answer (score 1):

This works...

```
import asyncio
import json
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%S')
root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.INFO)

async def readChunks():
  # this is basically a dummy alternative for reading csv in chunks
  df = [{"chunk_" + str(x) : [r for r in range(10)]} for x in range(10)]
  for chunk in df:
    await asyncio.sleep(0.002)
    root.info('readChunks: next chunk coming')
    yield chunk

async def send(row):
    j = json.dumps(row)
    root.info(f"to be sent: {j}")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.002)


async def main():
    i = 0
    root.info('main: starting to read chunks')
    async for chunk in readChunks():
        for k, v in chunk.items():
            root.info(f'main: sending an item')
            #await asyncio.gather(send({k:v}))
            stuff = await send({k:v})
        i += 1
        if i > 5:
            break
        #print(f"item in main via async generator is {chunk}")

##loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
##loop.run_until_complete(main())
##loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    asyncio.run(main())
```

... At least it runs and finishes.

---

The issue with stopping an async generator by reaking out of an `async for` loop is described in bugs.python.org/issue38013 and looks like it was fixed in 3.7.5.

However, using

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.set_debug(True)
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

I get a debug error but no Exception in Python 3.8.

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-8' coro=<<async_generator_athrow without __name__>()>>
```

Using the higher level API `asyncio.run(main())` [with debugging ON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#enabling-debug-mode) I do **not** get the debug message. If you are going to try and upgrade to Python 3.7.5-9 you probably should still use `asyncio.run()`.

Comment: Do you have debug on? - Let me try that - I'm using 3,8.

Comment: Nothing reported with debug mode on - not sure I can trace that problem without 3.7 on my computer, I'll look through the docs.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - looks like it is - https://bugs.python.org/issue38013 - it *appeared* in 3.7.1 then was *fixed* in 3.7.5.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I was using 3.7 because by using 3.8 I was not able to install some libs which were in C code available.

Comment: @spyder - looks like it was fixed in 3.7.5 - if it won't break your libraries, upgrade to 3.7.5-3.7.9.

Answer (score 0):

The problem  is simple. You do early exit from loop, but async generator is not exhausted yet(its pending):

```
...
if i > 5:
    break
...
```

Comment: @7u5h4r, and Alex: yes, my intention was to break the iteration. But the way I am doing is... bad at least. I am looking for the proper and prof. way. So want to find the way where and how to cancel and which part.

Answer (score 0):

Your `readChunks` is running in async and your loop. and without completing the program you are breaking it.

That's why it gives `asyncio task was destroyed but it is pending`

In short async task was doing its work in the background but you killed it by breaking the loop (stopping the program).